# Sending a mail without `to` method in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-mail

I want to send a mail via laravel. For some reason, I only want to set the `cc` before calling the `send` method:

```
Mail::cc($cc_mail)->send(new MyMailAlert());
```

Then I define the recipient (`to`) directly in the `build` method of my Mailable class:

```
$this->subject($subject)->to($to_email)->view('my-mail');
```

But it fails:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::cc()

How can I send a mail without knowing the recipient before sending it in the `build` method? In other word I want to set the recipient (to) directly in the `build` method and I don't know how to do this.

Comment: any specific reason why you want to do this? and what do you mean by `build` method?

Comment: @imrealashu the build method of my mailable class: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#generating-mailables The reason is I don't know the recipient before doing some stuff in my mailable class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cc` is documented in [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#sending-mail), but I can't find the method or property in the `Illuminate\Mail\Mailer` source code, neither in the [Laravel API Documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.html). So you can't use it this way.

But `Illuminate\Mail\Mailable` has the `cc` property. So, if you want to add the `cc` before sending and add the `to` on the build method, you need something like this:

*MyMailAlert.php*

```
class MyMailAlert extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject($this->subject)->to($this->to)->view('my-mail');
    }
}
```

In your controller:

```
$myMailAlert = new MyMailAlert();
$myMailAlert->cc = $cc_mail;

// At this point you have cc already setted.

Mail::send($myMailAlert); // Here you sends the mail
```

Note that the build method uses `subject` and `to` properties of the mailable instance, so you have to set it before sending.

I'm not sure from where are you retrieving your `$subject` and `$to_email` in your build method example, but for my example you have to give these values to `$myMailAlert->subject` and `$myMailAlert->to`. You can use your custom variables in the build method, but given that the class already has these properties, custom variables aren't needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hack to deal with this problem:

```
Mail::to([])->cc($cc_mail)->send(new MyMailAlert());
```

So just add a `to()` method with an empty array and it works. It's still a hack, I'm not really sure it will work in the future.